# What's the issue in getting all values in $_POST after form submission in following case?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, form-submit

Following is the HTML of a form:

```
<form action="add_rebate_by_product.php" role="form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="company_id" id="company_id" value="46">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="products[1]" id="products[1]" value="9">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="products[2]" id="products[2]" value="11">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pack[1]" id="pack[1]" value="10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[1]" id="quantity[1]" value="20">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="volume[1]" id="volume[1]" value="30">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="units[1]" id="units[1]" value="7">    
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount[1]" id="amount[1]" value="40">                            
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_start_date[1]" id="rebate_start_date[1]" value="2014-05-01">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_expiry_date[1]" id="rebate_expiry_date[1]" value="2014-05-15">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applicable_states[0]" id="applicable_states[0]" value="1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applicable_states[1]" id="applicable_states[1]" value="7">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applicable_states[2]" id="applicable_states[2]" value="11">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_total_count[1]" id="rebate_total_count[1]" value="5000">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="products[1]" id="products[1]" value="10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="products[2]" id="products[2]" value="8">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pack[2]" id="pack[2]" value="100">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[2]" id="quantity[2]" value="200">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="volume[2]" id="volume[2]" value="300">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="units[2]" id="units[2]" value="10">    
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount[2]" id="amount[2]" value="400">                            
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_start_date[2]" id="rebate_start_date[2]" value="2014-05-16">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_expiry_date[2]" id="rebate_expiry_date[2]" value="2014-05-31">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applicable_states[0]" id="applicable_states[0]" value="31">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applicable_states[1]" id="applicable_states[1]" value="44">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applicable_states[2]" id="applicable_states[2]" value="48">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applicable_states[3]" id="applicable_states[3]" value="49">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applicable_states[4]" id="applicable_states[4]" value="50">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_total_count[2]" id="rebate_total_count[2]" value="9000">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</button>
</form>
```

After submission of this form I'm getting below array in `$_POST` which is wrong, not showing all the values on form. Why? I sthere any mistake in naming the fields?

```
Array
(
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [company_id] => 46
    [products] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 8
        )

    [pack] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 100
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 200
        )

    [volume] => Array
        (
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 300
        )

    [units] => Array
        (
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 10
        )

    [amount] => Array
        (
            [1] => 40
            [2] => 400
        )

    [rebate_start_date] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2014-05-01
            [2] => 2014-05-16
        )

    [rebate_expiry_date] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2014-05-15
            [2] => 2014-05-31
        )

    [applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
            [1] => 44
            [2] => 48
            [3] => 49
            [4] => 50
        )

    [rebate_total_count] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5000
            [2] => 9000
        )

)
```

Comment: What exactly is missing in the array below? sorry, but it is a bit much to see at first sight. please provide more detailed information and less useless information.

Comment: what values are missing?

Comment: You have a few conflicting names e.g. `applicable_states[0]`.

Comment: Please try to be more specific with what value you are looking to receive via POST. I am very much confused about what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using the same name for multiple HTML input fields.

e.g.:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="products[1]" id="products[1]" value="9">
....
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="products[1]" id="products[1]" value="10">
```

You're explicitly telling HTML to use Key 1 on Products array for 2 inputs.
If you want to get all your values back with default index, don't create them with index.

`products[]` should do the trick. Then your products will be uploaded in order, with index 0 - x in corresponding order in which the elements were created i.e:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="products[]" id="products[]" value="9">
....
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="products[]" id="products[]" value="10">
```

Can be accessed using:

```
$_POST['products'][0]; # Will = 9
$_POST['products'][1]; # Will = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the name 'products' and 'applicable_states' twice. To work around this problem, use it like this instead:

Your first product:

```
products[1][1]
products[1][2]

applicable_states[1][1]
applicable_states[1][2]
applicable_states[1][3]
```

Your second product:

```
products[2][1]
products[2][2]

applicable_states[2][1]
applicable_states[2][2]
applicable_states[2][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple fields with the same name. They are being recorded and then written over later on in the form.

In your form you have:

```
<input ...  name="products[1]" value="9">
```

and later:

```
<input ... name="products[1]" value="10">
```

So it is only storing the second one.